# QT : Disable keyboard shortcut for quitting mac application or identify allow only closebutton event to quit application

Tags: python, macos, qt, python-2.7, python-3.x

In Mac Command + Q keyboard shortcut quits most of the applications.

In my case, I want to disable it for my application which I have developed in QT.

Or Is there any way to identify the close event raised by clicking close button of application window, If I can identify it, then I will not proceed to quit for rest of the close event calls by overriding the close function in QT.

Surely I can find a light to go where I wanted with anyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the QtGui.QApplication::events() method to receive this (command + q) Mac OSX keyboard shortcut close event and ignore it.

Below is my sample pyqt (code to achieve it.

```
#! /usr/bin/python 
import sys 
import os
from PyQt4 import QtGui 
class Notepad(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Notepad, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300,300,300,300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Notepad')
        self.show()
        self.raise_()
    #def keyPressEvent(self, keyEvent):
    #    print(keyEvent,'hi')
    #    print('close 0', keyEvent.InputMethod)
    #    if keyEvent.key() != 16777249:
    #        super().keyPressEvent(keyEvent)
    #    else:
    #        print(dir(keyEvent))
    #        return False
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
            "Are you sure to quit?", QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | 
            QtGui.QMessageBox.No, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()
def main():
    app = Application()
    notepad = Notepad()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

class Application(QtGui.QApplication):
    def event(self, event):
        # Ignore command + q close app keyboard shortcut event in mac
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Close and event.spontaneous():
            if sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
                event.ignore()
                return False
```

Thanks everyone